# Moving an Alcatel I-211M-L using Fiberoptic connection

Tags: fiber, optical

I have an Alcatal I-211M-L that I'd like to move. Is it possible to buy fiberoptic couplers and cables to extend the range of the fiberoptic cable, or do I need to call Verizon to have them move it? What should I buy, if so? Thanks!

Specifically, would the coupling and cables I need be multi-mode, and if so, what size? I'm sure the connector is an SC connector on the ONT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it uses a normal SC/APC connector, so something like this should be working; WAN uses single mode almost exlusively, a green connector indicates Angled Physical Contact which is used with SMF only.
[image]

Comment: Would the coupling and cables I need be multi-mode, and if so, what size? I'm sure the connector is an SC connector on the ONT.

Comment: Single mode is much more likely, especially with a green plug/socket. Have you checked the cable for any markings?

Comment: Cool, thanks. The cable says `SAMSUNG OPTICAL CABLE 01 12/15 SS-946IC1 - 001 SMF - MBR 5.0MM E343109 (UL) OFNR C(UL) OFN-FT4 1838 MT`.

Comment: SMF = single-mode fiber

Comment: Neat. The green connectors indicate APC. And from what I can read, there's only one size of single-mode fiber. So that's everything I need to buy the connectors, correct?

Comment: @Don01001100 yes that is correct, you should accept Zac’s answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There will be some loss at each coupling, and you must take into account the loss budget and the total loss in the link.

The cabling you need depends on the existing cabling, and you must match the existing cabling.

Comment: Would the coupling and cables I need be multi-mode, and if so, what size? I'm sure the connector is an SC connector on the ONT.

Comment: That depends on the existing cabling. I would recommend that if you need to ask these questions, you hire a professional for an hour to do this for you.